# ¿Como puedo reemplazar $_SESSION por una consulta preparada?

Tags: php, mysqli

Pues aquí con una duda, actualmente tengo querys donde pido x información y al final una clausula `WHERE` donde pido esa información sobre el id de la sesión actual, es decir solamente del usuario activo en ese momento, y quiero adoptar una consulta preparada porque el tener la variable `$_SESSION` me hace demasiado vulnerable a inyecciones sql.

Esto es lo que tengo actualmente:

```
if(isset($_GET['id_user'])){
sql "SELECT nombre, apellidos, edad FROM users WHERE id  = '".$_GET['id_user']'";
}
```

Lo que quiero es esto:

```
sql = "SELECT nombre, apellidos, edad FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$id = $_POST['id'];
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt) {        
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $Resultado = get_result($stmt);        
    while ($row = array_shift($Resultado)) {

    }

}
```

Pero no entiendo como la consulta tomará solo el id del usuario de la sesión actual:

Entendería que esto id = ? en esta linea se especifica que solo selecciona los datos de ese usuario en especifico?

Espero y alguien pueda ayudarme con este problema

Gracias a todos.

Comment: Solo una guía: durante el proceso de autenticación satisfactoria del usuario deberias guardar en $_SESSION[] el id del usuario. Cada vez q lo necesites, mientras la sesión este activa, tendras ese dato en dicho arreglo.

Comment: Para tomar el ID de la sesión actual debes primero asignar el ID del usuario a la sesión tal y como dijo Francisco. Y ya que esté asignado en el array lo puedes acceder de manera asociativa $_SESSION["id_usuario_actual"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código está bien, salvo algunos errores de ortografía <s>y de lógica...</s>

Me explico:

- Aquí <s>`sql`</s>  falta el signo de `$`
- <s>El `while` no es necesario si usas `get_result`.</s>. Sí hace falta el `while`, realmente `get_result` no funciona como `fetchAll`de PDO. De todos modos mostraré una forma más fácil de obtener un array asociativo. Ojo, `get_result` no funcionará si no tienes mysqlnd instalado.

Todo lo demás es como dices, corrijo el código y explico en comentarios:

```
/*
   (a) Aquí, ?  es un marcador de posición, es como si le dijeras
   "ahí va un dato, luego te digo qué dato es, para que no me hagan trampa
*/
$sql = "SELECT nombre, apellidos, edad FROM users WHERE id = ?";
/*
   Aquí lo importante es que $id  tiene que ser tu dato real, 
   no sé si se encuentra en la clave id  de POST o en la clave 
   id_user  de GET, eso depende de ti  ...
*/
$id = $_POST['id'];  //o bien $_GET['id_user']
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt) {  
    /*
       (b) Aquí se indica lo que se prometió en (a), o sea
           se le pasa el dato a la API para que lo revise, vea
           que no hay trampa y si no la hay, ejecute la consulta
           esto y el prepare son el núcleo de la protección contra inyección SQL
           La "i"  indica que es un dato de tipo (i)nteger
    */      
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    /*El while no es necesario, porque get_result ya te devuelve un array con los datos*/
    $Resultado = get_result($stmt);        
    $arrDatos=array();
    while ($row = $Resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
            $arrDatos[]=$row;
    }
    /*Aquí dispones de $arrDatos como un array asociativo de resultados*/
    var_dump($arrDatos);   
}
```